# Route depending if user is an artist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to set up my routes depending if the user is an artist. So for example, something like:

```
namespace 'dashboard' do
    if current_user.is_artist
       get '/settings', :to => 'users#edit', :as => 'account_settings'
       put '/settings', :to => 'users#update', :as => 'account_settings'
       delete '/settings', :to => 'users#destroy', :as => 'account_settings'
    else
       get '/settings', :to => 'artists#edit', :as => 'account_settings'
       put '/settings', :to => 'artists#update', :as => 'account_settings'
       delete '/settings', :to => 'artists#destroy', :as => 'account_settings'
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, I cannot access current_user in routes.rb. However, the logic of the code above, explains what my intentions are.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: You should remove this logic into application controller level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing table doesn't run at the context of a specific user. This is because it routes the request before reaching your session management code, so it can't tell who's the current user.

I can think of two solutions:

1. Render your settings links through some method that rewrites them if the user is an artist. This way 'artists' and 'users' get different URLs.
2. Add a before_filter to your UserSettings controller that catches requests from artists and redirects them to ArtistSettings (not sure of your internal structure, but you probably get the general idea).

Comment: Yea this seems to work, except my URL will now look something like http://localhost/dashboard/artists/1/edit instead of http://localhost/dashboard/settings. I would like the URL to be http://localhost/dashboard/settings for artist and user

Comment: Then you may have to take another route :) Use a single controller to support both, and have your public methods call different private methods based on whether the user is an artist or not. Not the first design I'd recommend, but simple enough and will preserve a single routing endpoint for both.

Comment: BTW, why is it some important to use the same /dashboard/settings endpoint for all users? What's wrong with something like /dashboard/settings/artist and dashboard/settings/user ?

Answer (score 0):

from what you have it looks like you have set up a role called artists. all you have to do to make your current_user method work is: in your account controller you can set up a before filter like saying before_filter :check_user_role :only => :account_setting. then you would set your account_settings for the various roles and their various redirects_to call methods you have. i am working on a similar project and it works for me. i hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a piece of middleware that figures out the user on a level before it hits the actual application. This is what warden/devise are doing for example. Add the user object to the env variable and you can access it anywhere lower in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing file simply determines which controller action is being invoked based on the URL.  You can map both artists and users to a single controller, and place the logic for which screen to render in that controller by looking at the user.  By default, controllers render a view that is based on the name of the controller and method, but you're free to override this and render whatever view you want.  Use your route to dispatch requests to the appropriate edit/update/destroy actions, and put your user/artist logic into those actions to render either the users/edit.html.haml or the artists/edit.html.haml file...

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Elad, the routing itself can not tell if the current user is an artist or not.

If you want to keep a single url with two differents behaviours and views, you may go with a single controller such as :

```
def settings
    if current_user.is_artist
        do something
        render :action => "artist_settings"
    else
        do something else
        render :action => "users_settings"
    end      
end
```